# How to compare a column value with multiple values from another column in the same table in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to compare column `user_id` with another column `order_id` in the same table `Orders`.

If a `user_id` has multiple distinct `order_id`'s, then I need to default `order_id` to `'00000'`. If `user_id` has two same `order_id`'s, then that `user_id` should have only one entry.

Input table: `Orders`

| user_id | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| A234 | 87655 |
| A234 | 89765 |
| A234 | 98723 |
| R678 | 09874 |
| R678 | 09874 |

Expected output:

| user_id | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| A234 | 00000 |
| R678 | 09874 |

Comment: Use `GROUP BY user_id` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

Simple aggregation would work with `case` expression :

```
select user_id, 
       case when min(order_id) <> max(order_id) then 00000 else min(order_id) end as order_id
from orders 
group by user_id;
```